# Any difference between "I suggested that we eat out tonight" and "I suggested eating out tonight?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the difference in nuance and meaning, if any, between the following two sentences?

1. I suggested that we eat out tonight.
2. I suggested eating out tonight.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference would be that "I suggested that we eat out tonight." is concerned with only the speaker and other(s) involved. "I suggested eating out tonight." could pertain to anyone, including or excluding the speaker.